# Google Visualization API - Line and Scatter on one Chart

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-visualization

Does any one know if it is possible to use the Default Google Scatter Chart in the Google Visualizations Gallery to draw a scatter chart that has both a series with points only, a series with a line of best fit and on top of this a set of lines across the chart indicating limits.  i.e. at +/- 20% etc.

The chart we need is actually a [Control Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_chart) with multiple series and individual formatting of each series displayed on the chart. i.e some series with only points other series with a line of best fit.

Does any one know of a Control Chart that has already been done using the Google Visualization API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working with the google visualization api for a while and searching the web I would have to say that the answer here is no.

You would have to build your own custom chart and from working with the api for a while I would rather do this with another charting library like jqPlot.

Answer (score 1):

You can make separate line sets in the google scatterchart.  The examples are on the scatterchart page.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/scatter_charts.html

Comment: That is with the image chart api not the visualization api, they are two different apis